# Solving $x^2 y''(x) + 6x y'(x) - 9y(x) =0$ with similar techniques that are used to solve algebraic equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, algebraic-equations

Consider the ODE
$$x^2 y''(x) + 6x y'(x) - 9y(x)  =0 .$$

It is clear that we can solve the ODE by the method of reduction of order. However, if we "see" the function $y$ as some constant just for a second, we can easily identify this equation as an algebraic equation *similar* to 
$$(x-3)^2 = 0.$$

### Question:

Is there any method for solving this kind of ODEs that are similar to solving algebraic equations as above ?

**Motivation:**

I mean for a given $x = x_0$, the function will have some fix value, so (bear with me for a second) if we plug $x_0$ into $y(x)$ without putting the value $x_0$ to $x$ in the coef. of the ODE (we are going to plug it into, but see this as there is some delay in the process :) ), we can treat the equation as an algebraic equation, and this can be done for any values of $x$, and this kind of thouhgt lead me to above question about whether such a thing can be justified rigorously ?

Comment: Isn't it a Cauchy-Euler ODE?

Comment: @ResidentDementor Yes, it is actually.

Comment: Your motivation is nice but, I think you are mixing two concepts with eachother.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your equation is not equivalent to 
$$
(xD-3)^2y=0
$$
as $x$ and $D=\frac {d}{dx}$ do not commute. Indeed you get $Dxf(x)=f(x)+xf'(x)=(1+xD)f(x)$ so that
$$
(xD-3)^2=xDxD-6xD+9=x(1+xD)D-6xD+9=x^2D^2-5xD+9.
$$

In reverse it means that you would have to factorize
$$
x^2D^2-6xD+9=(xD)^2-7xD+9=(xD-3.5)^2-3.25.
$$
or in the given equation
$$
x^2D^2+6xD-9=(xD)^2+5xD-9=(xD+2.5)^2-15.25.
$$

---

Once you have this factorization $(xD-a)(xD-b)y=0$ you can form an adapted first order system
$$
(xD-b)y=v\\
(xD-a)v=0
$$
where you usually get powers of $x$ and their linear combinations as solutions.

Comment: Greatly done!;;

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Substitutung $$y(x)=x^\lambda$$ we get the equation $$\lambda^2+5\lambda-9=0$$

Comment: How did you see that ? Is there any mathematically rigorous way of seeing this ?

Comment: @onurcanbektas : Euler-Cauchy ODE are linear ODE of the form $\sum_{k=0}^n c_kx^ky^{(k)}(x)=r(x)$ with constant coefficients $c_k$. Check your sources to see when this monomial trial solutions works, needs to be modified or (rarely) does not work. Substitute $x=e^t$ to discover connections to linear ODE with constant coefficients.